# How do I make windows XP output all bootstrap information?

Tags: linux, windows, boot

In linux we can make it output bootstrap instructions,

what about windows?

Answer (score 1):

When you boot in safe mode (Press F8) you can see the output.

You can also you procmon from Sysinternals to log everything as the machine boots.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for the scrolling screen of text...it's not great, but it does help with identifying driver issues, a bad driver will cause a hang on the last line of output...which incidentally, is the driver you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.windowsreference.com/general/how-to-create-a-bootlog-in-windows-2000xp-and-later/) shows you how to select "Enable Boot Logging" when you press F8 during boot up. It also shows how you can edit `c:\boot.ini` and add a `/bootlog` option.